# How to trigger the AC condition on Dancing Scarves during a full-round attack as a Two-Weapons fighting Rogue?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, movement, actions

I found the armor "[Varisian dancing scarves](http://aonprd.com/EquipmentArmorDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Varisian%20dancing%20scarves)" which give a +2 AC only if moving around at least 10 feet. And as a Two Weapons fighting Rogue (Unchained), I would like to find a way to be able to use this armor and keep my full-round attack available in melee range.

I already have the 5-foot move, which mean I just need to find a way to be able to move another 5 feet in the same round to enable this armor AC.

**So, is there a way to be able to make another 5-foot move, or extend the first one by 5 feet? A magic item or a feat available to rogues?**

Currently, I found :

- [Following Step](http://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Following%20Step) which allow an immediate 10 feet move when an opponent attempt to move away. **Prerequisites:** Dex 13, Step Up
- [Improved Sidestep](http://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Improved%20Sidestep) which allow a 5-foot immediate move when avoiding an opponent melee attack. **Prerequisites:** Dex 15, Dodge, Mobility, Sidestep.

Taking both feats could enable the armor to work most of the time, but they are quite taxing in feats: total of 5 feats. But I do plan to take Dodge and Mobility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR: The [Circling Mongoose](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/circling-mongoose-combat/) feat would be better for a TWF rogue as it has better synergy with the Sneak Attack. And it allow the condition on [Dancing Scarves](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/armor/dancing-scarves/) to apply.**

---

There is another option which cost less than the Outslug Sprint feat [pointed out by @Mouza](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/134617/is-there-a-way-to-move-at-least-10-feet-and-keep-a-full-round-action-as-a-rogue/134619#134619): **the [Circling Mongoose](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/circling-mongoose-combat/) feat**.

Unlike [Outslug Sprint](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/outslug-sprint-combat/) which would cost a total of 6 feats, the [Circling Mongoose](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/circling-mongoose-combat/) feat would only cost 4 feats.

So what's the deal? Would [Circling Mongoose](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/circling-mongoose-combat/) be better? No so fast! The greater is the power, the greater is the risk which come with it.

### 1) The [Outslug Sprint](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/outslug-sprint-combat/) path

Taking the [Outslug Sprint](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/outslug-sprint-combat/) path will give us the following benefit:

- +2 dodge AC and +2 to the damage roll when taking a 5-foot step
- Strike at +1 case will using [Lunge](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/lunge-combat-final/).
- the 5-foot step is in fact a 10-foot step.
- no more -2 AC when using [Lunge](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/lunge-combat-final/)

This is quite potent, but there isn't much synergy with the rogue standard way of doing damages: the Sneak Attack (or **SA** for short).

### 2) The [Circling Mongoose](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/circling-mongoose-combat/) path

> **Benefit**: When you are adjacent to a foe, as a full-round action, you can take a full-attack action to make melee attacks against the foe, moving 5 feet before each attack. You must move 5 feet before each melee attack you make, and can’t exceed your maximum speed, exceed your maximum number of attacks in a round, or attack any other target until the beginning of your next turn.
>
> You must remain adjacent to the foe, and your movement provokes attacks of opportunity as normal unless you succeed at the appropriate Acrobatics checks. If your first attack against the foe hits, you are considered to be flanking the foe on your second attack. Subsequent attacks made as part of the full-attack action continue to be treated as if you were flanking the foe until one of your attacks misses, at which point your attacks are treated normally.

Taking the [Circling Mongoose](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/circling-mongoose-combat/) path will give us the following benefit:

- Been able to flank an opponent all by ourselves if an attack hit (quite interesting with a rogue to do SA).
- +1 dodge AC from the [Dodge](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/dodge-combat-final/) feat.
- +4 dodge AC when moving in an opponent territory from the [Mobility](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/mobility-combat-final/) feat.
- Taking a 5-foot step before each attack in a [Circling Mongoose](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/circling-mongoose-combat/) full-round action.
- the [Spring Attack](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/spring-attack-combat-final/) full-round action and it's hit and run tactics.

With the following risk: giving opponents Attacks of Opportunities (or **AoO** for short) between each 5-foot step.

If we want to use the [Circling Mongoose](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/circling-mongoose-combat/) as a rogue, putting lot of points into the [Acrobatics](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/acrobatics) skill will help a lot. Also the +4 dodge AC from Mobility does help too.

Other feats with a synergy in using this path:

- The [Canny Tumble](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/canny-tumble-combat/) feat, which give a +2 attack modifier on the next attack when using acrobatics to avoid AoO and allow SA on the first attack. Quite a good synergy with [Circling Mongoose](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/circling-mongoose-combat/).
- The [Acrobatic](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/acrobatic-final) feat, which give +2 (and +4 at level 10 in the skill) to acrobatics checks.

Rogue talents:

- The [Confounding Blades](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo-rogue-advanced-talents/confounding-blades-ex) advanced talent forbid an opponent its AoO against a rogue which was able to do a SA before. This talent as a condition on the [Slow Reactions](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo-rogue-talents/slow-reactions-ex/) base talent.

Rogue Archetypes:

- The Skirmisher trait form the [Scout](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/archetypes/paizo-rogue-archetypes/scout/) archetype does work with [Circling Mongoose](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/circling-mongoose-combat/).

### 3) Conclusion

The [Circling Mongoose](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/circling-mongoose-combat/) path would be a better option for a TWF rogue. And with the same cost in feats as for the [Outslug Sprint](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/outslug-sprint-combat/), we would gain more opportunities to to SA. And in this case, does trigger the condition on the [Dancing Scarves](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/armor/dancing-scarves/).

Comment: This is a good answer that could be improved by quoting the relevant text for Circling Mongoose

Comment: @linksassin, I made this answer quite late this night, and still need to improve it. And I hope to do so today. Also, I will try the point out each drawback with each feats path.

Answer (score 5):

Both Following step and improved sidestep aren't what you want.
The first just allow to make a 5 f eet step even if you used sidestep in the enemy's round.

> Sidestep:
>
> Whenever an opponent misses you with a melee attack, you may move 5 feet as an immediate action so long as you remain within that opponent’s threatened area. This movement does not provoke attacks of opportunity. If you take this step, you cannot take a 5-foot step during your next turn. If you take an action to move during your next turn, subtract 5 feet from your total movement.

As you can see Improved Sidestep say this:

> Benefit: After sidestepping an opponent’s missed attack using the Sidestep feat, you may still take a 5-foot step during your next turn, or you may move up to your full speed if you take an action to move during your next turn.

Following step instead is used **only** during enemy's turn so there is no way you can use it and immediatly after make a full attack...

...fortunally for you there is a way, but is really expensive from a feat perspective:

[Outslug Sprint](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/outslug-sprint-combat/)

> While using Outslug Style, you can move an additional 5 feet when making a 5-foot step.

tl; dr: The feats you have listed don't do what you think, use this instead. [Outslug Sprint](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/outslug-sprint-combat/)

Comment: So, making a move during the round of an opponent, doesn't count in the total feet movement you make in your next turn? As state in "lesser" version, these feat do consume part of your available movements in your next turn. Shouldn't it count in the total distance moved in the next turn?

As for the Outslug Sprint, that's indeed a way. But it's even more costly in feat… :-/

Comment: Moving during enemy's turn is not equal as moving during **your** turn. The object is pretty specific on this: "Whenever you move at least 10 feet **during your turn**, you gain a +2 armor bonus to AC until the beginning of your next turn."

Outslug style is expensive, yes, but i can assure you is really strong and, without multiclassing you can take it at level 10 with a rogue/unchained rogue. Ofcourse, if you want this feat earlier, you can dip 2 level in fighter and i think you can have this feat around level 8.